# Missing class reference in build.xml

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

When I gave ant **myproject-war**, I got the following error. Can anyone help please?

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Documents and Settings\personal\Desktop\project files\myproject\bu
ild.xml:167: taskdef A class needed by class org.apache.jasper.JspC cannot be fo
und: javax/servlet/ServletContext
```

Answer (score 0):

Gotta add a JAR containing javax.servlet.ServletContext to your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest and classpath. They might not be including the necessary jar.

For instance: `classpathref="some_classpath"` could go in the `javac` tag, where `some_classpath` equals

```
<path id="some_classpath">
    <pathelement location="${someJar.jar}"/>
    <pathelement location="${another.jar}"/>
</path>
```

Also, you jar's manifest should have something like:

```
<manifest>
    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="../lib/another.jar ../lib/someJar.jar"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: hi this is my tag where i found jspc. could you plz help
<property environment="env" />

  <taskdef classname="org.apache.jasper.JspC" name="jasper2">

   <classpath id="jspc.classpath">

    <pathelement location="${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" />

    <fileset dir="${env.tomcat.home}/bin2">

     <include name="*.jar" />

    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${env.tomcat.home}/server/lib">

     <include name="*.jar" />

    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${env.tomcat.home}/common/lib">

     <include name="*.jar" />

    </fileset>

   </classpath>

  </taskdef>

Answer (score 0):

In ant new tasks can be defined (taskdef). Some of these tasks need you to put java-libraries into the classpath of ant. That can be realized by copying the appropriate jar into the lib/ext-directory of the ant-installation.

Answer (score 0):

You need a jar in your classpath for the target that's running JspC that contains javax.servlet.ServletContext.  So, for example, if you're using Tomcat, servlet-api.jar might be the jar you're looking for.  If you're doing GWT, gwt-user.jar might be the jar.  Depends on your context.

Comment: i have servlet.api.jar in my project's lib folder

Comment: Also, you need to make sure that that jar is added to your classpath definition in your build.xml file for the target that's invoking JspC.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Ant tasks with dependencies not supported in the core API.

From the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#optionalTasks):

> Ant supports a number of optional
>   tasks. An optional task is a task
>   which typically requires an external
>   library to function. The optional
>   tasks are packaged together with the
>   core Ant tasks.

Use the [manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) to locate the optional tasks and add the required [dependencies](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies) to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Ant doesn't take spaces in the classpath.